# Create a carousel, show number of elements, hide and show next number of elements

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to create a carousel where it first shows the first 7 images, and in an internval it should show the first 7 images, then fade them out and show the next 7 images.

And when all the images are showed, it should start over again and have an infinite loop.

How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<div class='flow'>
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/1.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/2.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/3.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/4.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/5.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/6.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/7.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/8.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/9.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/10.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/11.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/12.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/13.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/14.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/15.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/16.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/17.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/18.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/19.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/20.png' />
   <img src='assets/library/en/references/21.png' />
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
x = 21;

setInterval(function() {

if(x>=21){

    x = 21;    
}

x = x - 7;
y = x + 7;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.flow > img:nth-child(1n+'+y+')').fadeOut().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 500);
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.flow > img:nth-child(1n+'+x+')').fadeIn().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
    }, 3000);

}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a lot of approach on this and there's a lot of jQuery plugins for image carousel (unheap.com is a good repository of jquery plugins, you can explore here). I'm still new with jQuery and I have the same problem a while ago.

I feel comfortable doing this with .each() function rather than manipulating with the nth-child selector.

```
var len = $('.flow > img').length;
var by = 7;
var start = -1; //since first index is 0, I'll start lower than that
var curr = start;

setInterval(function(){
    if(curr >= len - 1){
        curr = start;
    }

    $('.flow > img').each(function(index, element) {
        if(index > curr && index <= curr + by){
            $(this).fadeIn(500);
        }else{
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

    curr += by;

}, 3000);
```

please see my fiddle:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/aLmGM/1/)